# Angular - Not able to redirect to another component using Bing Map push pin click

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, bing-maps

Bing Map Push pin is clicked, but Router gets undefined in the console log.

so unable to redirect. If I added router.navigate in the constructor it is working perfectly.

Below is my code

```html
 import { Component,  ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { } from "bingmaps/scripts/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All"
    import {Router,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

        @Component({
          selector: 'device-map',
          templateUrl: './device-map.component.html'  
        })
         
        export class DeviceMapComponent implements OnInit{
          @ViewChild('myMap') myMap;
          
          constructor(public router: Router,  public route: ActivatedRoute,) {
            console.log(this.router); }

          pushpinClicked(e){
            console.log("I am clicked");
            console.log(this.router);
            this.router.navigate(['/Dashboard'], { queryParams: { deviceId: 
             e.target.metadata.title } }); } 

            ngOnInit(){              
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(this.myMap.nativeElement, {
                credentials: 'My key', center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6149, -122.1941)
            });

              var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), {
                title: "Microsoft", description: "City Center", visible: false,
            });

            infobox.setMap(map);
            var randomLocation = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getLocations(1, map.getBounds());
            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(),  {  title: 'Microsoft' });
            pin.metadata = { title: 'Device 1',  description: 'Pin discription' };
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', this.pushpinClicked);
            map.entities.push(pin);
          } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a way to add navigation for push pin click (Bing map). 
Arrow function is required.

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click',  () => {
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');});
```